# Node.js: download gzip file, unzip it and save files with rename

Tags: node.js, stream, zlib

I need to write node.js script that downloads gzip file that contains multiple files and then unzips it with file names changed. I also trying to make it with minimal number of external npm packages (preferably none). As first step im trying to download and unzip:

```
const https = require('https');
const zlib = require('zlib');
https.get(url, function(response) {
    var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
    response.pipe(gunzip);
});
```

Unfortunately I see this error:

> Error: incorrect header check

Any idea how to fix it? BTW if I download gzip into file I can successfully unzip it.

Comment: About `if I download gzip into file I can successfully unzip it.`, in this case, is the file downloaded using your script? In your situation, when the response value is seen, what value will you get? Because from `Error: incorrect header check`, I'm worry that the correct data might not be downloaded. For example, because of the redirect. How about this? If my understanding of your situation was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Yes I load file using https.get and stream it to save as file. One important note I want to emphasize is zipped file is collection of files

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, the url is not redirected. The gzip data can be directly downloaded from the URL. Is my understanding correct? And, about `zipped file is collection of files`, in this case, is your data "zip" which is not "gzip"?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes its gzip file. I ended up using 3rd party npm library "unzipper"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue. By the way, from `I ended up using 3rd party npm library "unzipper"`, I thought that your file is the zip file which is not gzip file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format) How about this?